# Batch CSV handling empty tokens while using usebackq in for-loop

Tags: csv, batch-file

I found many topics on the problem of handling empty tokens, but i can't get it to work on my code. The only difference i can see is that i am using *usebackq* which the others didn't, but if i remove it, the rest of the code won't work. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

The code is supposed to take a csv, switch the value in the 3rd column with another value that is stored in *Mitarbeiter.txt* and do the same with the last value and it's pair in *Lohnarten.txt*, then write that into the new csv:

```bat
@Echo Off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(Set Datei=lohn_prod.csv)
(Set MA=Mitarbeiter.txt)
(Set LA=Lohnarten.txt)
(Set Ziel=eGecko.csv)

For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=;" %%A In ('FindStr "[0-9]*;.*" "%MA%"') Do (
    If Not Defined $[%%A] Set "$[%%A]=%%B") 
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=;" %%A In ('FindStr "[0-9]*;.*" "%LA%"') Do (
    If Not Defined $[%%A] Set "_[%%A]=%%B")

For /F "Delims=" %%X In ("%Datei%") Do (
    Set Line=%%X
    Set Line=!Line:;=";"!
    (For /F "UseBackQ EOL=; Skip=13 Tokens=1-7 Delims=;" %%A In ("!Line!") Do (
        Call Echo=%%~A;%%~B;%%$[%%~C]%%;%%~D;%%~E;%%~F;%%_[%%~G]%%;)
    )
)>%Ziel%
Exit/B
```

I am trying to encapsulate my semicolon-delimiters in quote marks and remove them before writing everything into the new file, but that doesn't work.

Instead of getting this csv:

```
15;01.09.2016;105;160,25;1;2100;210;
15;01.09.2016;105;40;1;;217;
15;01.09.2016;105;5;72;;;
15;01.09.2016;107;184;1;2213;210;
15;01.09.2016;107;7,25;1;;213;
15;01.09.2016;107;16;1;;216;
```

into this desired form:

```
15;01.09.2016;40200;160,25;1;2100;101;
15;01.09.2016;40200;40;1;;103;
15;01.09.2016;40200;5;72;;;
15;01.09.2016;40201;184;1;2213;101;
15;01.09.2016;40201;7,25;1;;423;
15;01.09.2016;40201;16;1;;102;
```

i instead get this, where the last values get moved into the 2nd last position if there is an empty token in front of them and thus also won't get replaced by the values in *Lohnarten.txt*:

```
15;01.09.2016;40200;160,25;1;2100;101;
15;01.09.2016;40200;40;1;217;;
15;01.09.2016;40200;5;72;;;
15;01.09.2016;40201;184;1;2213;101;
15;01.09.2016;40201;7,25;1;213;;
15;01.09.2016;40201;16;1;216;;
```

Comment: There is a neat little hybrid batch/jscript utility that Dave Benham wrote that helps parse delimited files because of the known issues with the FOR command. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702

Comment: Thanks, will look into it, but i'd like to know why my code doesn't work, as i suspect it's just some minor syntax-error that i don't see.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error! I also made the other changes and it's still working. I am new to batch-scripting and got help with the code. The original code didn't have delayed expansion enabled, thus the call i guess. I had to enable it to get around the actual problem with the empty fields. I found a solution now where Set Line is used differently and moved the UseBackQ up as you already suggested and this did the trick, i don't understand though, why adding the delimiters to Set Line actually works. Could someone maybe explain it after i post the solution?

Comment: @ThorkaMae, I provided an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40286527) now and deleted my comments, including some explanations what I did; if you need more details, just comment on the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code, which make me disbelieve that it produces the output you claimed (perhaps just copy-paste issues); anyway, here are the issues:

- in the `if defined` query in the second `for /F` loop, there seems to be the wrong variable `$[%%A]` queried, I think it should read `_[%%A]`;
- instead of `Set Line=!Line:;=";"!`, you should write `Set Line="!Line:;=";"!"`, so each semicolon-separated item is enclosed within `""`; then the `~` modifier of the `for /F` variables works reliably for later removal of the quotes;
- nesting of the redirection part `>` is wrong, you need to put parenthesis around the outer `for /F` loop rather than the inner one, because otherwise, every line is redirected separately, overwriting the previous ones; I put the redirection part to the beginning of the parenthesised block, just because I like it more that way, but you can put it at the end of the block either; by the way, the redirection target should be quoted like `"%Ziel%"`;
- the `UseBackQ` option must be stated at the outer `for /F` loop but not at the inner one;

Here are some additional issues:

- the `Set` syntax should be changed so that the entire assignment expression appears in between `""` to avoid trouble with special characters;
- since you have delayed expansion enabled anyway, there is no need to use `Call Echo %%Variable%%`, you can use `Echo !Variable!` instead;
- I changed the indent and the positions of closing parentheses so that the code becomes more legible;

Here is the fixed script:

```dos
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Datei=lohn_prod.csv"
Set "MA=Mitarbeiter.txt"
Set "LA=Lohnarten.txt"
Set "Ziel=eGecko.csv"

For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=;" %%A In ('FindStr "[0-9]*;.*" "%MA%"') Do (
    If Not Defined $[%%A] Set "$[%%A]=%%B"
)
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=;" %%A In ('FindStr "[0-9]*;.*" "%LA%"') Do (
    If Not Defined _[%%A] Set "_[%%A]=%%B"
)

> "%Ziel%" (
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%X In ("%Datei%") Do (
        Set "Line=%%X"
        Set Line="!Line:;=";"!"
        For /F "EOL=; Skip=13 Tokens=1-7 Delims=;" %%A In ("!Line!") Do (
            Echo %%~A;%%~B;!$[%%~C]!;%%~D;%%~E;%%~F;!_[%%~G]!;
        )
    )
)
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, works as intended. The Skip=13 is needed because the original csv has a 13-line header which i don't need in the new file and it seems that this and the placement of UseBackQ in the wrong For Loop were the main issues. I guess the lines in the nested for-loop are beeing worked through line by line and with Skip that line gets removed completely. Putting it into the outer For-Loop makes it then work as intended. Also thanks for pointing out the redirection part, i didn't understand it at all, but got it now and it makes the code execute much faster than in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used aschipfls suggestions here and a solution from another question which did the trick. I don't understand though, what this line actually does:

```
Set Line=%%X;;;;;;;
```

Could someone explain it to me?

The tweaked code that now works is this (i used **Line:;=;"** instead of **Line:;=";"** at the end because else there was one quote mark after the first token that didn't get removed):

```bat
@Echo Off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(Set Datei=lohn_prod.csv)
(Set MA=Mitarbeiter.txt)
(Set LA=Lohnarten.txt)
(Set Ziel=eGecko.csv)

For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=;" %%A In ('FindStr "[0-9]*;.*" "%MA%"') Do (
    If Not Defined $[%%A] Set "$[%%A]=%%B") 
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=;" %%A In ('FindStr "[0-9]*;.*" "%LA%"') Do (
    If Not Defined _[%%A] Set "_[%%A]=%%B")

Type NUL > "%Ziel%"
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%X In ("%Datei%") Do (
    Set Line=%%X;;;;;;;
    Set Line="!Line:;=;"!"
    (For /F "EOL=; Tokens=1-7 Delims=;" %%A In ("!Line!") Do (
        Echo=%%~A;%%~B;!$[%%~C]!;%%~D;%%~E;%%~F;!_[%%~G]!;)
    )
)>>%Ziel%
Exit/B
```